# Liferay 7 - Redirect to OIDC provider login page

Tags: liferay-7

I am using Liferay DXP 7.0 fp 100 and OIDC authentication.

OIDC worked fine, but users must select ‘OpenID Connect’ and an OIDC provider from the login portlet before reaching my OIDC provider’s login page.

Most users don’t know what ‘OpenID Connect’ is, and we have only one OIDC provider. I would like to route users directly to my OIDC provider’s login page without going through the login portlet.

My understanding is whenever a user needs to access a protested page, the user will be routed to /c/portal/login by following [here](https://%20https://help.liferay.com/hc/en-us/articles/360017878352-Converting-StrutsActionWrappers-to-MVCCommands-), but it did not work. /login/login was not overriden. Do I need to create dummy MVCRenderCommand as well?

```java
@Component(
        immediate = true,
        property = {
                "javax.portlet.name=" + LoginCmdPortletKeys.LOGINCMD,
                "mvc.command.name=/login/login",
                "service.ranking:Integer=100"
        },
        service = MVCActionCommand.class
)
public class LoginMVCActionCommand extends BaseMVCActionCommand {
    @Override
    protected void doProcessAction(ActionRequest actionRequest, ActionResponse actionResponse) throws Exception {
        actionResponse.sendRedirect("/home/-/login/openid_connect_request?p_p_state=maximized&_com_liferay_login_web_portlet_LoginPortlet_saveLastPath=false&_com_liferay_login_web_portlet_LoginPortlet_OPEN_ID_CONNECT_PROVIDER_NAME=XXXX");
    }
}
```